# UNO DataGrid / GridView / ListView takes too much time to bind

Tags: uno-platform

This has been raised several times, but it is just not practical to deliver a system with such slow binding. We have changed the DataGrid to GridView based on the recommendations, but to bind 15 records it takes 25 seconds, be it ListView or GridView.

Are we missing something in the UNO WinUI Solution which is causing this lag?

Thanks

Neeraj

Comment: Do you have code to share (xaml and the viewmodel maybe)? Which platform do you observe the lag?

Comment: `<!--[PARENT PAGE - XAML]-->
<local:UC_SearchCriteriaView />`

Comment: `//[ParentPageViewModel]
public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem> EnquiryReasons
{
    get { return GetValue(() => EnquiryReasons); }
    set { SetValue(() => EnquiryReasons, value); }
}


Onload()
{
 --searchCriteriaData object is hydrated with EnquiryReasonsNote
 EnquiryReasons = new ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem>(searchCriteriaData.EnquiryReasonsNote);
}`

Comment: `[UC_SearchCriteriaView - USER CONTROL]
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.EnquiryReasons, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="430"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ParentPage">
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                <TextBlock Margin="35,1,0,0" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
`

Comment: `
[UC_SearchCriteriaView - CODE BEHIND]
public sealed partial class UC_SearchCriteriaView : UserControl
{
    private ParentPageViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as ParentPageViewModel;
}
`

Comment: @matfillion, 

Just to summarise the above code:

1. A user control is hooked into the parent page.
2. Within the view model of the Parent Page, the object is hydrated.
3. With in the user control the ParentPageViewmodel is passed as a DataContext.
4. The object is binded to the <ListView> within the UserControl.

Thanks